# Problems Connecting Gnosis Safe to an Dapp through WalletConnect

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, walletconnect

A customer of ours is trying to connect to our Dapp with their safe wallet through wallet connect. Other wallet type work correctly through wallet connect, but with a safe wallet on Goerli a contract is called from react with ethersjs. The ethers js contract call never returns and does not throw an error.
The Safe wallet gets the transaction request, which is approved and completed, but the react app does not get a return from the contract call, and so does not have access to the transaction.

Is there anything unique to connecting with gnosis safe wallets through wallet connect? Is there even a way of seeing that it is a gnosis safe wallet when the connection comes through wallet connect?

Answer (score 0):

We stopped supporting Goerli network in 2023. You might be able to process some transaction (maybe with degraded functionality), but Safe{Wallet} (the react app) will likely not pick up this transaction and display it as intended. We recommend switching to Sepolia or any other [supported test network](https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/supported-networks) to restore functionality.

Hope it helps! Louis